# stat: print time in "long-iso" format

Tags: bash, ls, time, stat

For my script, I would like to have `stat` command to print time in a nice, human friendly, way: `2015-02-04 00:48:31`. `ls` calls this format `long-iso` and it can be used like this:

```
$ ls -lA --time-style=long-iso .bashrc 
-rw------- 1 michael michael 5740 2015-02-04 00:48 .bashrc
```

However, there is no such switch for `stat`. The option `%y` for "human-readable time" looks like this:

```
$ stat -c'%A %h %U %G %s %y %n' .bashrc
-rw------- 1 michael michael 5740 2015-02-04 00:48:31.160827516 +0100 .bashrc
```

Is there any simple way to make `stat` print time in "long-iso" format?

I need to use `stat` rather than `ls` because I need to adjust which columns (attributes) get printed and in which order.

I am using `stat` form package `coreutils` verssion `8.13-3.5` on Debian.

Comment: Use `stat` with `--printf=FORMAT` option and format the date as per your taste, e.g.: `stat --printf='%A %h %U %G %s %.16y %n\n' .bashrc` or if you want it to show the seconds too: `stat --printf='%A %h %U %G %s %.19y %n\n' .bashrc`

Comment: @don_crissti - exactly what I needed. If you want to put it as answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `--printf` option [as suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184814/stat-print-time-in-long-iso-format#comment308062_184814) by @don_crissti:

```
stat --printf='%A %h %U %G %s %.16y %n\n' .bashrc
```

If, for whatever reason, you can't do that you can parse the output of `stat -c '%y':

```
$ stat -c'%A %h %U %G %s %y %n' .bashrc | awk '{$7=substr($7,1,8); $8=""}1;'
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 9737 2015-02-01 18:12:18  .bashrc
```

Or you can use GNU `date` to convert it:

```
$ date -d "2015-02-01 18:12:18.665916181 +0200"
Sun Feb  1 19:52:18 EET 2015
$ date -d "2015-02-01 18:12:18.665916181 +020" +"%F %R:%S"
2015-02-01 19:52:18
```